# Moving hand fast cause [handdetector-7] process to die

Tags: ros, hand-interaction

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've successfully run MIT's hand detection demo. However, the recognized hand in rviz will stopped moving, if my hand moves a little faster. It's because the [handdetector-7] process died. As long as I kept my hand moving slow, the package runs fine. Complete error message:

```
detectskelhands: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:278: Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel, true>::Block(XprType&, Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel, true>::Index) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3>, int BlockRows = 3, int BlockCols = 1, bool InnerPanel = true, Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel, true>::Index = int]: Assertion `(i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) && (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) && i<xpr.rows()) ||((BlockRows==XprType::RowsAtCompileTime) && (BlockCols==1) && i<xpr.cols()))' failed.

got hand 0.19, 0.240678, 0.765086 [handdetector-7] process has died [pid 3817, exit code -6].
```

Does this happen to anyone of you?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29623/moving-hand-fast-cause-%5Bhanddetector-7%5D-process-to-die/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a bug in the hand detector.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0